# Why am I getting this exception while running running this OpenCV program?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I use Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.3.0.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <ml.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<class T> class Image {
  private:
  IplImage* imgp;

  public:
  Image(IplImage* img = 0) {
      imgp = img;
  }

  ~Image() {
      imgp = 0;
  }

  void operator=(IplImage* img) {
      imgp = img;
  }

  inline T* operator[](const int rowIndx) {
      return ((T *)(imgp->imageData + rowIndx * imgp->widthStep));
  }
};

typedef struct {
  unsigned char b,g,r;
} RgbPixel;

typedef struct {
  float b,g,r;
} RgbPixelFloat;

//typedef Image<RgbPixel>       RgbImage;
//typedef Image<RgbPixelFloat>  RgbImageFloat;
typedef Image<unsigned char>  BwImage;
//typedef Image<float>          BwImageFloat;

double crossCorrelation( IplImage* img1, IplImage* img2 ) {
    double corr;
    int M = img1->width;
    int N = img1->height;

    BwImage img_1( img1 );
    BwImage img_2( img2 );

    CvScalar img1_avg = cvAvg( img1, NULL );
    CvScalar img2_avg = cvAvg( img2, NULL );

    double sum_img1_img2 = 0;
    double sum_img1_2    = 0;
    double sum_img2_2    = 0;

    for( int m = 0; m < M; ++m ) {
        for( int n = 0; n < N; ++n ) {
            sum_img1_img2   = sum_img1_img2 + (img_1[m][n] - img1_avg.val[0]) * (img_2[m][n] - img2_avg.val[0]);
            sum_img1_2      = sum_img1_2    + (img_1[m][n] - img1_avg.val[0]) * (img_1[m][n] - img1_avg.val[0]);
            sum_img2_2      = sum_img2_2    + (img_2[m][n] - img2_avg.val[0]) * (img_2[m][n] - img2_avg.val[0]);
        }
    }

    corr = sum_img1_img2/sqrt(sum_img1_2*sum_img2_2);
    return corr;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/ANIMES~1/Documents/VISUAL~3/Projects/tutOpencv/tutOpencv/38.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    IplImage *img2 = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/ANIMES~1/Documents/VISUAL~3/Projects/tutOpencv/tutOpencv/39.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    IplImage *img1g = cvCreateImage( cvSize( img1->width, img1->height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    IplImage *img2g = cvCreateImage( cvSize( img2->width, img2->height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    std::cout << (double)crossCorrelation(img1g, img2g) << std::endl;
    std::system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug I always get this exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x013e157f in tutOpencv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00f3b00c.

I cannot make out, where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Add some breakpoints to figure out where your program is crashing